# Approximate an Integral using Taylor Expansion

Tags: calculus

I am doing evaluation of integral by using Taylor expansion. The integral is:
$$
{I} = \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - {\mu}x}}g\left( x \right)dx}
$$
where
$$
g\left( x \right) = \ln \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\alpha _i}{e^{ - {\mu _i}x}}} } \right)
$$
with $\mu,\mu_i, \alpha_i$ are possitive real numbers.
Using Taylor Series Expansion, I obtain
$$
g\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{l = 0}^R {\frac{{{g^{\left( l \right)}}\left( 0 \right){x^l}}}{{l!}}}  + {O_R}
$$
where $O_R$ is the remainder. Then $I$ can be approximated as
$$
{I} \approx \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - {\mu }x}}\sum\limits_{l = 0}^R {\frac{{{g^{\left( l \right)}}\left( 0 \right){x^l}}}{{l!}}} dx}
= \sum\limits_{l = 0}^R {\frac{{{g^{\left( l \right)}}\left( 0 \right)}}{{\mu^{l + 1}}}} 
$$
The point is I don't know whether these series are convergent. So my proof maybe not valid. If you guys have any ideas, please suggest.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma

Comment: So that approximation is valid if $\mu$ is large. What if $\mu$ is small? Are there any method to approximate that integral?